# Ruby - cant load bundler

Tags: ruby, bundler

I installed bundler with rvm gem install bundler. What is wrong here???

Also did reinstall with these option -

```
apt-get install libncurses5-dev libreadline5-dev libreadline-dev librequire-dev
rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125 --default
rvm reinstall librequire-dev libbundler-dev --with-readline-dir=/usr/include/readline



       $ rails new proj

           exist
       identical  README.rdoc
       identical  Rakefile
       identical  config.ru
       identical  .gitignore
       identical  Gemfile
           exist  app
       identical  app/assets/images/rails.png
       identical  app/assets/javascripts/application.js
       identical  app/assets/stylesheets/application.css
       identical  app/controllers/application_controller.rb
       identical  app/helpers/application_helper.rb
           exist  app/mailers
           exist  app/models
       identical  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
       identical  app/mailers/.gitkeep
       identical  app/models/.gitkeep
           exist  config
       identical  config/routes.rb
       identical  config/application.rb
       identical  config/environment.rb
           exist  config/environments
       identical  config/environments/development.rb
       identical  config/environments/production.rb
       identical  config/environments/test.rb
           exist  config/initializers
       identical  config/initializers/backtrace_silencers.rb
       identical  config/initializers/inflections.rb
       identical  config/initializers/mime_types.rb
        conflict  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
    Overwrite /root/src/config/initializers/secret_token.rb? (enter "h" for help) [Ynaqdh] y
           force  config/initializers/secret_token.rb
       identical  config/initializers/session_store.rb
       identical  config/initializers/wrap_parameters.rb
           exist  config/locales
       identical  config/locales/en.yml
       identical  config/boot.rb
       identical  config/database.yml
           exist  db
       identical  db/seeds.rb
           exist  doc
       identical  doc/README_FOR_APP
           exist  lib
           exist  lib/tasks
       identical  lib/tasks/.gitkeep
           exist  lib/assets
       identical  lib/assets/.gitkeep
           exist  log
       identical  log/.gitkeep
           exist  public
       identical  public/404.html
       identical  public/422.html
       identical  public/500.html
       identical  public/favicon.ico
       identical  public/index.html
       identical  public/robots.txt
           exist  script
       identical  script/rails
           exist  test/fixtures
       identical  test/fixtures/.gitkeep
           exist  test/functional
       identical  test/functional/.gitkeep
           exist  test/integration
       identical  test/integration/.gitkeep
           exist  test/unit
       identical  test/unit/.gitkeep
       identical  test/performance/browsing_test.rb
       identical  test/test_helper.rb
           exist  tmp/cache
           exist  tmp/cache/assets
           exist  vendor/assets/javascripts
       identical  vendor/assets/javascripts/.gitkeep
           exist  vendor/assets/stylesheets
       identical  vendor/assets/stylesheets/.gitkeep
           exist  vendor/plugins
       identical  vendor/plugins/.gitkeep
             run  bundle install
    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
            from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
            from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.2/bin/bundle:2:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing I do after installing RVM is install bundler to global gemset.

```
rvm use 1.9.3@global
gem install bundler
rvm use 1.9.3
```

When you install a gem to global gemset, it will be available in all gemsets (including default one) within the same ruby.

Comment: Is there any tips for windows users? Windows users cannot use rvm.

Answer (score 2):

What about simply `gem install bundler`?

Comment: Tried gem install bundler. Didn't work. 
This error is with every require statement, in bundler and even require 'any gem'.

Not sure where is this searching for gems and why not in the path they are installed.

Comment: # rvm use ruby-1.9.3-p125 --default
    Using /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125
# echo $GEM_PATH
    /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@global

Comment: # gem list -d bundler
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

bundler (1.1.2)
    Authors: AndrÃ© Arko, Terence Lee, Carl Lerche, Yehuda Katz
    Rubyforge: http://rubyforge.org/projects/bundler
    Homepage: http://gembundler.com
    Installed at: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125

    The best way to manage your application's dependencies

Comment: @FirstnameLastname What happens when you run `gem install bundler`?

Comment: I can install it - 
# gem install bundler
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/1.9.1/yaml.rb:56:in `<top (required)>':
It seems your ruby installation is missing psych (for YAML output).
To eliminate this warning, please install libyaml and reinstall your ruby.
Successfully installed bundler-1.1.2
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for bundler-1.1.2...
Installing RDoc documentation for bundler-1.1.2...

Comment: Getting the same error 0 run  bundle install
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- bundler (LoadError)
        from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
        from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bundler-1.1.2/bin/bundle:2:in `<main>'

Comment: This worked for me if I use sudo, i.e. `sudo gem install bundler`

Answer (score 1):

I used

```
sudo gem install bundler
```

and then I was able to proceed without the error and my rspec tests run

```
$ rspec near_time_in_words.rb 
.....

Finished in 0.00171 seconds
5 examples, 0 failures
```

:)